# Preciso pegar um valor depois de uma string em uma expressão regular

Tags: java

Comecei a estudar hoje expressão regular estou tentando colocar em pratica algumas idéias não encontrei em nenhum lugar onde poderia resolver um problema que estou tendo...

Então e o seguinte, tenho uma String:
NOME="Ana" IDADE="22" SEXO="F"

Preciso pegar o valor do nome vai estar entre aspas, mas com este código que estava trabalhando não esta indo...

Pattern n = Pattern.compile("NOME=/"([^"]+)"/");

Matcher matcher = n.matcher(entrada);

Esta me retornando erro, procurei na internet não encontrei onde esta o problema. Sou nova nesse assunto um pouco leiga.

Se eu conseguir esse eu posso consigo fazer os outros da String depois.. Muito obrigada!

Comment: Você deveria usar a barra invertida para escapar as aspas, não? `"NOME=\"([^\"]+)\""`

Comment: Obrigada, tinha me esquecido.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Uma das opções seria:

```
NOME=\"([^\"]+)\" IDADE=\"([0-9]*)\" SEXO=\"([A-Z])\"
```

Nesse contexto você obtém a nome no grupo 1, a idade no grupo 2 e o sexo no grupo 3.

Grupo 2  = procura valores numéricos entre 0 e 9 , o * indica que pode aparecer O ou mais números.

Grupo 3 = procura valores entre A maiúsculo e Z maiúsculo.

Comment: Obrigada, me ajudou muito